# Remove Double-Click Zoom D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a stripped down force directed graph with zoom/pan capability: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/36b27a0b6f8c485c25995e7c223def3c

Here is the zoom portion:

```
var zoomHandler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomActions);

zoomHandler(svg);

function zoomActions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
  }
```

I would like to remove the zoom capability for double-click, and only keep it for scrolling. Based on the docs and other questions, I know I must include `.on("dblclick.zoom", null)` somewhere. However, I cannot figure out where to place this piece of code. In addition, I'm not sure if I am properly using "svg" and "g" to group my elements, which may be contributing to the issue. I have seen the other questions related to this issue, and have not been able to fit them into my situation.

How should I remedy this? Thank you for any insight you all might have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling the zoom function on the svg selection...

```
zoomHandler(svg);
```

... you have to add the listener to the same selection:

```
svg.on("dblclick.zoom", null)
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/42745557a8602692d9dc98c33a327d29

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you. I swear I tried that earlier - but I must have been being dense. Should I be calling the zoom function on the svg selection? What's the point of creating a g group in the next line if I am calling it on svg anyway?

Comment: Traditionally, D3 coders call zoom on `<g>` elements.

Comment: That's what I gathered - thank you. Changing the code to `zoomHandler(g)` and placing it below `var g = svg.append("g")` results in a zoom that works for the first couple scrolls, then breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var zoomHandler = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", zoomActions);

 zoomHandler(svg);

  svg.call("zoom").on("dblclick.zoom", null);


function zoomActions(){
   g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}
```